# Academic Job Interviews for Asst Prof Positions in Ireland

Tags: professorship, job, interview, assistant-professor, ireland

I have an upcoming interview for an asst prof position in a university in Ireland. I am wondering what questions are asked in such interviews. I am used to the hiring process in the US. It will be my first time being interviewed for a university in Ireland. Thanks!

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/119795/etiquette-for-academic-job-interviews-in-ireland

Answer (score 2):

I am a USA academic who interviewed unsuccessfully in Ireland (but successfully in Scotland). I was partially unsuccessful as I realized a few hours in that I did not want to work there but as they had flown me over I did not want to be unpolite and leave the interview.

**Biggest Three Differences**

- I got to meet all the other applicants. We were in the same room and
  called one-by-one to do our presentations. I ended up really wanting
  another candidate to get the job.
- Only one person on the panel was a faculty member (chair) in the department.
- No dinner with faculty, not a tour of the town, no real contact with the department
  at all aside from the odd quick hello as we passed their offices.